Передача небольших данных в реальном времени local server, сторонний сервис, клиент
Необходимо передавать данные с локального ПК, который передает текущий вес в реальном времени с напольных весов.
Есть инструменты специально созданные под переадресацию небольших данных?
Что я имею ввиду? С локал ПК отправляю данные на этот сервис и с него по ссылке забираю эти данный с любого устройства через запрос.
Ищу такое решение чтобы избежать аренды VPS/VDS, траты времени на изучение и настройки всей этой кухни.
Если такого нет, то подскажите лучший вариант. Спасибо!

Размер данных никак не влияет на факт доступности или недоступности устройства через сеть
